# How do I use the layout I made in my Main Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a layout that I like, and want to put it in my app. I am working in the MainActivity.kt file, and want to "call"(?) the layout.xml file that I made.
What I have:
[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2G5I.png)
[Layout (don't make fun of me it's my first time trying this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJEjF.png)

I tried adding setContentView(R.layout.layout) to my onCreate function. Not sure what I was expecting, but nothing seemed to happen.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout)
    }
}
```

Comment: that is the preview that is generated by the composables. you're confusing xml and compose. delete everything you have in that file except for the onCreate method and then RUN the app. that preview is what is generated by compose with @Preview

Comment: @a_local_nobody, how do we know that the OP is using Compose, instead of Views?

Comment: @RajatGupta by looking at the images they've posted

Answer (score -2):

I hope you're trying to replace your layout file in the activity multiple times.
if so please try to explore the [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments) it will full fill your need.

Comment: even if OP used a fragment here it wouldn't make a difference, there's nothing wrong with the code they have now. they're just looking at the compose preview and not running the app, so a fragment wouldn't make a difference here